# Modifying Footnote Plugin for Descriptive Title Attributes

Tags: plugins, php, functions, customization

I've been struggling for a couple hours now to get this working... Hopefully someone here can help me.

I just started using the wp-footnotes plugin, and I'm trying to set the title attribute on backlinks to "Return to footnote # in the text." where # = the footnote number.

Below is what I tried, putting the $id_num variable in the title attribute, but it ends up just displaying as the number of footnotes that exist. [You can see this at my development site on the first post](https://defomicron.net/dev/).

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

It's quite a bit, so I'll paste the code in at the end:

```
    // Display identifiers      
    foreach ($identifiers as $key => $value) {
        $id_id = "identifier_".$key."_".$post->ID;
        $id_num = ($style == 'decimal') ? $value['use_footnote']+$start_number : $this->convert_num($value['use_footnote']+$start_number, $style, count($footnotes));

        $id_replace = $this->current_options['pre_identifier'].'<a href="'.$id_href.'" id="'.$id_id.'" title="'.$id_title.'">'.$id_num.'</a>'.$this->current_options['post_identifier'];
        if ($this->current_options['superscript']) $id_replace = '<sup>'.$id_replace.'</sup>';
    }

    // Display footnotes
    if ($display) {
        $start = ($start_number != 1) ? 'start="'.$start_number.'" ' : '';

            if ($style == 'symbol') {
                $data = $data . '<span class="symbol">' . $this->convert_num($key+$start_number, $style, count($footnotes)) . '</span> ';
            }
            $data = $data.$value['text'];
            if (!is_feed()){
                foreach($value['identifiers'] as $identifier){
                    $data = $data.$this->current_options['pre_backlink'].'
<a href="'.( ($use_full_link) ? get_permalink($post->ID) : '' ).'#identifier_'.$identifier.'_'.$post->ID.'" class="backlink"
title="Return to footnote '.$id_num.' in the text.">&#8617;</a>'
.$this->current_options['post_backlink'];
                }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you reduced the quantity of code to the bare minimum.

Comment: I edited it down a bit but I'm not 100% what is the bare minimum for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to replace this:

```
"Return to footnote '.$id_num.' in the text."
```

with this:

```
"Return to footnote '.$identifier.' in the text."
```

The `$id_num` is used in the "Display identifiers" loop, but what you want to edit is the "Display footnotes" loop.